# Is string subsequence of another. Solution not accepted, but runs fine in my IDE

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm learning JavaScript and was working on some DSA problems. Here is the one I am trying to solve:

> Write a function `isSubsequence` which takes in two strings and checks whether the characters in the first string
> form a subsequence of the characters in the second string. In other words, the function should check whether the
> characters in the first string appear somewhere in the second string, without their order changing
>
> 1. `isSubsequence('hello','hello world') //true`
> 2. `isSubsequence('sing','sting') //true`
> 3. `isSubsequence('abc','abracadabra') //true`
> 4. `isSubsequence('abc', 'acb') //false`

This is my code:

```js
const isSubsequence = (str1, str2) => {
  const createCharObj = (string) => {
    let outputObj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      if (outputObj[string[i]]) {
        outputObj[string[i]]++;
      } else {
        outputObj[string[i]] = 1;
      }
    }
    return outputObj;
  };
  let charObj1 = createCharObj(str1);
  let charObj2 = createCharObj(str2);
  let compare = "";

  for (let key in charObj2) {
    if (charObj2[key] < charObj1[key]) {
      return false;
    } else {
      let exceed = charObj1[key];
      let i = 0;
      while (i < exceed) {
        compare += key;
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
  return compare === str1;
};

console.log(isSubsequence("hello", "hello world"));
console.log(isSubsequence("sing", "sting"));
console.log(isSubsequence("abc", "abracadabra"));
console.log(isSubsequence("abc", "acb"));
```

I understand that my solution is not efficient, but I believe that the logic is proper.

However, when I run it on an IDE of Udemy, I get an error saying:

> expected false to be true

Yet when I run it on VS code, there was no issue. Please let me know where I did the mistake.

Comment: It is exactly same output is impossible to be different between IDE's

Comment: that's a unit testing (jasmine) message, it doesn't mean your code is wrong, also I don't know why it should apply to your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is not correct. The code challenge site (Udemy) is feeding your code with *other* inputs as well, and for some of those (not the ones you listed) your code returns the wrong result.

It assumes that if a letter in the second string corresponds to a letter in the first string, that it must be the one that is also in the right sequence. This is not necessarily true for the first time this character is encountered in the second string.

For instance, your code will return the wrong result for this input:

```
console.log(isSubsequence("abc", "acabc"));
```

This is because in the second string the first occurrence of "c" is before the first occurrence of "b", but it should have ignored that first "c".

Hints:

> The main iteration should be over the *first* string, not the second.

> Once a character from the first string is found in the second string, all characters that *precede* that character in the second string should be completely ignored in any next search.

Spoiler solution:

> `const isSubsequence = (str1, str2) => {
>      let j = -1;
>      for (let ch of str1) {
>          j = str2.indexOf(ch, j + 1);
>          if (j === -1) return false;
>      }
>      return true;
>  };`

Comment: Another, simpler, solution could of course be: `new RegExp(str1.split("").join(".*")).test(str2)`.

Comment: Yes, although you would have to escape special characters.

Comment: Right about the escaping of characters, but wrong about the padding. The RegExp works as shown, I tested it with the given strings.

Comment: Yes, you're of course right about that second part. Removed that mention of additional `.*`.

Comment: The regex solution may also lead to a potential complexity issue, as it employs a backtracking mechanism that will not bring any profit, but will make the efficiency O(n*m), while it can be done in O(n+m)

Comment: We'll, brevity comes at a price :D !